# Android Horizontal Layout with text wrap functionality

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout

I want to create an layout, in which I should be able to add views dynamically and it should expand horizontally in a flow.

Here are things that I've tried:

1. Flow-Layouts
   Problem with flow-layouts is that when using multiple textviews, if textview having long text, it takes whole textview to next line, but I want it to wrap the text and only move rest of the text to new line.
2. Spannable Textviews
   I want to assign individual id's to views because when it's clicked it should highlight and function accordingly but with spanning it's not possible.

[image: Sample I want to build]

Comment: The problem is ``View``s are basically rectangles, so it's impossible to have a View that fits the shape of that red text up there, for example. That's why the whole thing wraps to the next line, in a single block. I don't know what libraries and widgets are out there, but I feel like you might need to create your own custom logic here, so you can use ``Spannable``s to get the text layout you want, and handle touches so you can work out which bit of text has been clicked, and do something with it

Comment: @cactustictacs I've tried Spannables and by using it I achieved it somewhere. But I have to put custom views as well in it with which user can interact. so spannables won't work I think.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is faking it with multiple ``TextView``s somehow, so the red text up there is actually 3 (one per line). Probably a headache to get all that working, and pretty bad for accessibility, but at least it would use the standard "Views in a Flow" layout. Or you could leave gaps in the text and overlay the custom views in the spaces. You might be trying to do something pretty complicated here! But maybe there's already an easy solution someone knows about, I've only used Flow for the basics